# Self join in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I want to have following type of query in entity frame work

```
SELECT  c2.* 
FROM    Category c1 INNER JOIN Category c2
ON      c1.CategoryID = c2.ParentCategoryID
WHERE   c1.ParentCategoryID is NULL
```

How to do the above work in Entity framework...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I don't know much about EF, but that looks something like:

```
var query = from c1 in db.Category
            where c1.ParentCategoryId == null
            join c2 in db.Category on c1.CategoryId equals c2.ParentCategoryId
            select c2;
```

Comment: @Waheed: I don't know what you mean - you should be able to use that exact query in EF.

Comment: hello ,i have changed it to return List<Category> catergoyList then it  says u need to cast. how to cast var to List<Category> object?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: You don't cast it, because the result *isn't* a `List<Category>` - you call `ToList()` instead, e.g. `return query.ToList();`

Comment: I assume by "I need in EF", he probably means in a LINQ expression.

Comment: @Ellesedil: Um, this is a LINQ expression. In what way do you think this *isn't* a LINQ expression?

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to the fluent syntax.

Comment: @Ellesedil Well that certainly wouldn't change whether or not the OP could be used with EF.

Answer (score 2):

Just to tidy this up the following is a bit nicer and does the same thing:

```
var query = from c1 in db.Category
            from c2 in db.Category
            where c1.ParentCategoryId == null
            where c1.CategoryId == c2.ParentCategoryId
            select c2;
```

Answer (score 1):

In EF 4.0+, LEFT JOIN syntax is a little different and presents a crazy quirk:

```
var query = from c1 in db.Category
        join c2 in db.Category on c1.CategoryID equals c2.ParentCategoryID 
        into ChildCategory
        from cc in ChildCategory.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new CategoryObject 
        {
            CategoryID = c1.CategoryID, 
            ChildName = cc.CategoryName
        }
```

If you capture the execution of this query in SQL Server Profiler, you will see that it does indeed perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  HOWEVER, if you have multiple LEFT JOIN ("Group Join") clauses in your Linq-to-Entity query, I have found that the self-join clause MAY actually execute as in INNER JOIN - EVEN IF THE ABOVE SYNTAX IS USED!

The resolution to that?  As crazy and, according to MS, wrong as it sounds, I resolved this by changing the order of the join clauses.  If the self-referencing LEFT JOIN clause was the 1st Linq Group Join, SQL Profiler reported an INNER JOIN.  If the self-referencing LEFT JOIN clause was the LAST Linq Group Join, SQL Profiler reported an LEFT JOIN.